# Protractor throws "angular never provided resumeBootstrap"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js, protractor

I'm trying to just bootstrap a simple protractor test (in fact, is just to see it running). I have the following config file:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['../test/spec.js'],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox'
    },
}
```

a simple spec (taken from the tutorial):

```
// spec.js
describe('liverabbit homepage', function() {
    it('should have a title', function() {
        browser.get('http://localhost:1337/');

        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('New Sails App');
    });
});
```

and I've added this line to the html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
```

(before adding that line, protractor failed because it couldn't find angular).

I started the webdriver-manager, lifted my app (a sailsjs app) and run protractor with the spec.

Then, I got this one: "angular never provided resumeBootstrap"

Answer (score 3):

You need to not only have angular included, but also to have at least one angular application defined in that page. To fix the problem, just replace your  element with:

```
<body ng-app>
```

in your html.